# A hitman falls in love with a victim girl

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen this movie when I was very young (11 or 12). I am 19 now and I want to know the name of this movie. The movie is obviously produced before the 2000.

**Genre:**

Drama. Seen on television.

**What the movie is about**":

It is about a hit-man who invades a house for theft or murder (one of them). He kills everyone there. However, the girl (I do not remember if she was related to the victims) is found there sitting on stairs, sad, depressed and smoking. The hit-man feels compassion for her and starts developing a relationship with her.

Whether it was romantic or not, the hit-man and the girl are pictured inside a house taking care of flowerpot or a pot.

The movie ends with the hit-man killing himself with a bomb, in order to let the girl go to school again.

Anyone to identify this movie for me?

Comment: great film.  It was obvious then that Natalie portman was destined to be a star.

Comment: I want to point out that Mathilda's (Natalie Portman) family is _not_ killed by Léon the hitman (Jean Reno), but by some corrupt police; she goes to Léon for help.

Comment: Re: romantic. Mathilda: Leon, I think I'm kinda falling in love with you. Léon: [wiping himself off] How do you know it's love if you've never been in love before? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFWBJgirKfw

Comment: The Leon/Mathilda dynamic is equal parts touching and disturbing. Amazing movie. Luc Besson at his best.

Comment: If I may say so: Look for the DIRECTOR'S CUT version. The other version has been expurged of "disturbing" material, mainly, where Mathilda explicitly tries to get Leon to see her as a woman, and not a teen girl.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This sounds like Luc Besson's [Leon: The Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on:_The_Professional) from 1994 with Natalie Portman about a hitman adopting a girl after her family is wiped out (he also finds her sitting and smoking on the stairs in his building). They also take care of a potted plant together. It ends in the manner you've described (he offs himself with grenades to take out the villain). The film gained a cult status and is now considered one of Besson's best (it's currently #27 on [IMDb's Top 250](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) rated films of all time). Here's the trailer:

Comment: Hey @Walt, would you be interested in a movie-identification freelance job? Please let me know

Comment: @BukLau Very kind of you to offer, but I'm probably in no position to take you up on it. But I'll be happy to do it for free here, whenever I can. ;)